# CFFI Pass callback as parameter to another function

Tags: python, c, callback, python-cffi

Here is an explanation of my misunderstanding:

I have a class named Codex:

```
class Codex:
    ffi = FFI()
    def __init__(self):
        self.ffi = FFI()
        self.ClibDec = self.ffi.dlopen("...")
        self.ffi.cdef("""int CRD_Set(int handle, int property, void *value);
                         int CRD_Get(int handle, int property, void *value);
                      """)

    def funct1(self):
        handle = self.ClibDec."something"
        self.ClibDec.CRD_Set(handle, 0, funct2)

    @ffi.callback("int(*)(int, int)")
    def funct2(self, handle):

        status = 0
        self.ClibDec.CRD_Get(handle, 420, status)
        # do something

        return 0
```

My question is how can I call funct2 inside `self.ClibDec.CRD_Set` in my funct1 ?

I check several similar issues and the doc:
https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks-old-style

But I still not understand the usage of callback (old style)

Comment: simply use `self.funct2()`

Comment: If `int CRD_Set(int handle, int property, void *value);` is the signature of a C function you want to call from Python, then it does not take any callback function as parameter. `void*` is only compatible to data objects,

Comment: @Gerhardh Both POSIX and Windows require function pointers are convertible to `void*` and back without loss of information.  It would not surprise me in the least to encounter a generic API like this one, for which some values of `handle` and `property` expected a function pointer cast to `void *` as the associated value.

Comment: @Thib When you tried the sample code you have shown us, what _exactly_ happened?

Comment: @zwol If I remove `@ffi.callback("int(*)(int, int)")` it says:  `TypeError: initializer for ctype 'void *' must be a cdata pointer, not method`. If I let the ffi callback it doesn't recognize the C lib function `self.ClibDec.CRD_Get("....")` inside my funct2 but doesn't seem to complain about `void *`. I update my post to illustrate it

Comment: @zwol `self.ClibDec.CRD_Get(handle, 420, status) AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'ClibDec'`

Comment: You tell that the callback take two integers as arguments '(int, int)'. It does not matter that the first one is called 'self', you will get an int.

Comment: @ArminRigo If I do `@ffi.callback("int(*)(int)")`  it will result in `TypeError: OnStatus() missing 1 required positional argument: 'handle'` which weird because I have other python function of same prototype with `@ffi.callback("int(*)(int)")` which doesn't print this kind of error. For some of them write `@ffi.callback("int(*)(int, int)")` or `@ffi.callback("int(*)(int)")` change nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for code like this?  This would be the solution closest to what you're trying to write.

```
class MyClass:

    def funct1(self):
        handle = self.ClibDec."something"
        # make a cdata function pointer object that will call
        # back self.funct2(handle)
        cfnptr = ffi.callback("int(*)(int)", self.funct2)
        self.ClibDec.CRD_Set(handle, 0, cfnptr)
        # the cfnptr pointer must not be called after
        # the variable 'cfnptr' goes out of scope,
        # which occurs when funct1() returns here.

    def funct2(self, handle):
        ...
        return 0
```

Comment: It results in Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Not enough information to help, sorry.  We'd need at least the documentation of the `CRD_Set` and `CRD_Get` functions you're trying to call, and ideally a reproducible example that we can run ourselves; or you need to use a C debugger like `gdb`, maybe.